# Option delim_0 "\\dotfill" in makeindex ignored by texlive's makeindex?

Tags: texlive, indexing

I've a problem when making the index with a personal style file. Here is my file perso.ist

```
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "

heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"

delim_0 "\\dotfill"

delim_1 "\\dotfill"

delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

When I use `makeindex toto.idx`, I've no error; when I want to use my personal file with the command `makeindex -s perso.ist toto.idx`, texlive says he ignored 3 lines, and obviously, it is the 3 lines relating to the dots: delim_0 `\\dotfill` etc.

Do you know why?

Comment: I copied the lines above to an .ist file and it worked as expected. Could you provide a minimal example showing the problem? (Note that i am working with MiKTeX, I just saw that you referred to TeXlive.)

Comment: Yes, this is precisely the problem : works with miktex, doesn't work with texlive, but I didn't found any information on the net :-(

Comment: (sorry for removing and now reading the `texlive` tag. From the original question it was not clear that this problem was specific to TeX Live.)

Answer (score 6):

Could it be that you are using a file with windows line endings? If I create a perso.ist
with CR+LF line endings I get:

```
Scanning style file ./perso.ist......done (6 attributes redefined, 6 ignored).
```

but with just LF it works ok:

```
Scanning style file ./perso.ist......done (6 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
```

If you are using texlive on windows, I think this qualifies as a bug in the included makeindex.