# How to force output unix format idx file

Tags: indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [option delim_0 “\\dotfill” in makeindex ignored by texlive's makeindex ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/option-delim-0-dotfill-in-makeindex-ignored-by-texlives-makeindex)

This problem only happens in non-unix system (e.g. Windows).

`\makeidx` output the CR+LF in .idx file, and when using `makeindex filename.idx`, it reject all entries because of fail to identify the extra deliminator.

Although I can use `dos2unix` to fix it, is there any commands to force `\makeidx` to output unix format idx file?

Comment: Possibly a bug? See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/option-delim-0-dotfill-in-makeindex-ignored-by-texlives-makeindex)